# Android Studio svn: E200030: BUSY after being locked

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I am working on an app in Android Studio and we use subversion for version control.  After attempted to update, my project became locked.  I was unable to unlock it by doing a cleanup, which was what most people on here suggested.  Eventually, I unlocked it by going into the .svn wc database file and deleting the row in WC_LOCK.  This unlocked my project, but I still can't do anything because every time I try to do something with subversion, I get the svn: E200030: BUSY error.

I'm not sure why it thinks its busy, or if there really is some process running, how to stop that process.  I have tried restarting Android Studio, as that seems to be a common solution to a lot of Android Studio problems, but that hasn't helped.

Has anyone had issues with this?  If so, how did you resolve them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never quite found a solution - just had to save all of the source files, delete my project, and then start over pulling what we had in the repository, and adding in my changes from my saved source files.  If you are making lots of small commits, this should do fine, but if you have a bigger one, this could be troublesome...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Android Studio and SVN

1) Right Click on app

2) Subversion -> Cleanup